# Upgrading Cudnn version in Vertex AI Notebook [Kernel Restarting Problem]

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-vertex-ai, cudnn

**Problem**: *`Cudnn`* version incompatiable with *`tensorflow`* and *`Cuda`*, Kernel dies and unable to start training in Vertex AI.

Current versions:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.platform import build_info as build
print(f"tensorflow version: {tf.__version__}")
print(f"Cuda Version: {build.build_info['cuda_version']}")
print(f"Cudnn version: {build.build_info['cudnn_version']}")
```

- 

```
tensorflow version: 2.10.0
Cuda Version: 11.2
Cudnn version: 8
```

- 

As per the information (shown in attached screenshot) available [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu), *`Cudnn`* version must be 8.1.

[image]

A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70015687/upgrade-cudnn-to-8-2-in-google-colab) that is related to upgrading *`Cudnn`* in Google colab. However, it does not solve my issue. Every other online sources are helpful for Anaconda environment only.

How can I upgrade the *`Cudnn`* in my case?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this [article](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/user-managed/upgrade) by Google help you to solve your problem? Let me know whether this is helpful or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried several combinations of tensorflow, Cuda, and Cudnn versions in Google Colab and the following version worked [OS: Ubuntu 20.04]:

```
tensorflow version: 2.9.2
Cuda Version: 11.2
Cudnn version: 8
```

Therefore, I downgrated the tensorflow version in Vertex AI from 2.10.0 to 2.9.2 and it worked (solved only the incompatibility issue). I'm still searching the solution for Kernel restarting.

**UPDATE::**

The problem of Kernel Restatring got fixed after I changed the Kernel from *`Tensorflow 2 (Local)`* to *`Python (Local)`* in Vertex AI's Notebook as shown in the attached image [Kernel changing option is available on the right-top near the bug symbol].

[image]